# Webpack: how to reduce build time in development?

Tags: angular, webpack

I am working on a large `Angular 2` application and I am using `Webpack` for bundling and minifying.

The issue is that the build takes 6 minutes! So it is not practical for development.

I considered a) not building in development at all but use lazy loading instead and b) build the Angular 2 core files once and build my custom files every time.

But, I don't know if that's possible at all. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: do you build with aot?

Comment: Yes, I'm using AOT

Comment: It takes much more time, do you need it in development mode? I use it only for production and it serves quit quickly

Comment: Don't use AOT. Use Webpack watch mode. Additionally, Webpack can probably be configured to use UMD bundles from @angular packages

Comment: Could you show your webpack config file? And what version of webpack are you using? I had some performance problems (seconds) with ts-loader and I switched to [awesome-ts-loader](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader). Maybe could be that. But 6 minutes is a lot. Is really weird.